# JMS producer to send message to specific queue manager using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, jms, mq

I have application which consumes message from queue queuename1 and has header JMSReplyTo = queue://MQA1/queuename2. It then process that message and send response to queue provided in JMSReplyTo. As we have multiple queue managers like MQA1, MQA2, etc other consumer application expect message on queue manager provided in JMSReplyTo. I have code like below.

```
<route id="route1">
    <from uri="readJmsMq:queue:{{jms.read.queue}}?disableReplyTo=true&amp;exchangePattern=InOnly" />
    <bean ref="processInputMsg" method="processRequest" />
    <to uri="writeJmsMQ:{{jms..write.queue}}?disableReplyTo=true&amp;exchangePattern=InOnly" />
</route>
```

How can I publish message to same queue manager. I read so many things but did not find anything to implement using apache camel.